# Overriding save method in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I'm new to Ruby/Rails and I want to override the `save` method so I can do some checking inside myself before calling the actual `save` method, however, I am getting this exception for some reason:

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `save' for true:TrueClass>
```

This is my code for the module and class.

Module:

```
module OverrideSave

    def save
        super.save if some_condition_true
    end
  end
```

Class:

```
class CardTransaction
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created
  prepend OverrideSave

  field :type, type: String
  field :transaction_value, type: BigDecimal
  field :receipt_value, type: BigDecimal
  field :store_id, type: String

  belongs_to :card
end
```

I'm not sure what went wrong, any ideas?

Comment: `save` returns `true`?

Comment: Yes, save did execute (record created) and returned true, but I'm not sure why that exception happened

Comment: _"so I can do some checking inside myself"_ – you would typically use validations or a `before_save` callback (depending on what you are trying to do).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you try to call `save` on whatever `super` (i.e. `save`) returns? From your description, you want something like this:

```
def save
  # some additional work
  super
end
```

Comment: I have clarified the code a little. I wanted to intercept the original `save` call. The code is minimal so as to introduce the problem quickly

Comment: _"Why do you try to call save on whatever super (i.e. save) returns?"_ – I'd say the OP just wanted to call (the overridden) `save` and was not aware that `super` _is_ that method call.

Comment: Right, it seems probable.

Comment: Ah I get it now. Yes @Stefan was right. My idea of `super` was the instance of the class itself, not the method call, that's why I called `save` again. My understanding of the concept was wrong. Now I get what you mean. TIL!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to override the `save` method for above. You can use `before_save` [callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) in your model:

```
class CardTransaction
  before_save :do_some_validation

  private

  def do_some_validation
    # will get there before the save is called
    false if custom_validation
  end
end
```

Comment: Is it possible to stop the `save` operation if it failed the validation?

Comment: Yes you just have to return false

Comment: This is not a validation @MathieuLarouche. It is a callback which will abort the save if returned `false` from here. In validations, you need to set error on a field (or base object) to stop it from saving.

Comment: well, he talked about stopping the save, if he wants to add an error to a field he just has to add    errors.add(:field, "error message")

Comment: Starting with Rails 5 you have to use `throw :abort` by default instead of returning `false` in order to halt the callback chain.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Marek

```
module OverrideSave

    def save
        super if some_condition_true
    end
end
```

But it is not good behavior to override `save` method, it would be better to create a new method which would use save method, so you still have `save` method.

```
module OverrideSave
  def save_with_guard
     save if some_condition_true
  end
end
```

Comment: How do you teach Rails to use `save_with_guard` instead of `save` when using `create` / `update` etc?

Comment: @Stefan instead of calling .save you would call .save_with_guard on the object.

Comment: Sure, but there are other ways to save an object, e.g. via `update` or `save!` (with bang). Those methods would still call `save`, thus bypassing your checks.